# Sending zeroMQ messages to/from localhost - secure?

Tags: security, ipc, zeromq

I am trying to use zeroMQ for communicating between 2 processes. The message contains instructions from one process for the second to execute, so that from a security perspective it is quite important that only the proper messages are sent and received.

If I am worried about 3rd parties who may try to intercept or send malicious messages to the process, am I correct in assuming that as long as my messages are sent/received on IP 127.0.0.1 i am always safe? or is there any circumstance where this can be compromised?

Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions and security are usually two things you don't want to mix. The short answer to your question is that sending or receiving traffic to localhost (127.0.0.1) will not, under default conditions, send or receive traffic outside of the local host.

Of course if the machine itself is compromised then you are no longer secure at all.

Answer (score 2):

You've applied the `ipc` tag, which I assume means that you're using the `ipc://` protocol (if not, you should be if all of the communication is happening on one box).  In this case, you shouldn't be using IPv4 addresses at all (or `localhost`), but `ipc` endpoint names.  See [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#The-Naming-Ceremony) and [here](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-ipc).

For `ipc`, you're not connecting or binding to an IP or DNS address, but something much more akin to a local file name.  You just need to make sure both processes refer to the same filename, and that permissions are set so that both processes can appropriately access the directory (see the ZMQ docs for a little more info there, search for ipc).  The only difference between an `ipc` endpoint name and a filename is that you don't need to create the file, ZMQ creates the resource so both processes can communicate with the same thing.

As S.Richmond says, if your machine is compromised, then all bets are off, but there's no way to publish ipc endpoints to the internet if you use them appropriately.